# "If and who" correctly phrased

Tags: questions

First an example to clarify what im talking about:
If you are refering, for example, to a person you do now know the name and the location of, you would say something like this:

"He is the caretaker, i dont know who or where he is"

But what would you say if you would, for example, approach a room and do not know **IF** someone is inside and, if someone would be inside, **WHO** is inside?

Something like:

"This is Room 203, im not sure if and who is inside"

"..., im not sure if who is inside"

Is the only correct phrasing the long, unsatisfying sentence like that:

"..., im not sure if someone is inside and if yes, who it is"?

Or is there a way to formulate this like the well-working example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I'm not sure who, if anyone, is in there.'

Comment: That sounds good and works in my language too, thanks!